Spring Boot integration with angular
Is there a way to run my backend Spring Boot project along with the Angular frontend, without starting a separate Angular server? Can I deploy the entire application on the backend server only?

Yes, it is possible to integrate Spring Boot with Angular so they would run in one project. Try to follow this steps:

Build the Angular Application with an Angular CLI. Ready files should be generated in the dist/ folder.

Copy those files in the directory of your Spring Boot project. It is usually src/main/resources/static directory.

Configure Routing in Angular. If your Angular app uses client-side routing, you need to configure Spring Boot to forward all unknown requests to index.html so the Angular router can handle them.

Run or Package the Spring Boot Application.

Access Your Application. Once the Spring Boot application is running, both the frontend and backend will be accessible from the same URL (e.g., http://localhost:8080).



If your application becomes bigger, it is better to separate the frontend and backend for scalability reasons.
You should also check that your build process integrates this approach if you're automating CI/CD pipelines.
You can also check this tutorial.

Yes.
You can build the frontend and copy it over to the static resources of your Spring Boot application.
You can create a task in Gradle / Maven that will copy over the frontend build files from your frontend project (should be the "dist" folder since you're using Angular) and copy it over to /resources/static in your Spring Boot Application.
Articles such as this one explain this really well.

As @dmitry543 said is all right, however in point 3. you can just tell your Angular to use hash locations:
provideRouter(routes, withHashLocation())

so, you do not need to configure Spring Boot to forward any thing.
